# How do I install Sublime Text 2 full version?

Tags: sublime-text

I have followed the steps given in various blogs to install sublime text 2, but after installing when I use it i get the message as unregistered at the top. How can i get a full version of sublime text 2

Answer (score 3):

Purchase a license by visiting [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/buy). You'll get a license key. Then open up Sublime Text, go to Help > Enter License.